# How to add reference to an external dll file in asp.net core project

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Everytime I try to add reference to any dll file from my non asp.net core projects to my new asp.net core project i get this error message:

> .NET Core projects only support referencing .NET framework assemblies in this release. To reference
>   other assemblies, they need to be included in a NuGet package and
>   reference that package.

What should be happen here? is there a special way to do it?, seams there is something I am missing here which different than all previous asp.net version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now, you cannot directly add full .NET framework dll into ASP.NET core project (**netcoreapp1.0**) directly. You will have to create NuGet package.

If it is project specific dll then create local NuGet package. These are the steps we followed in our project to generate NuGet package-

1.Download `Nuget.exe` and place it in the folder where `.csproj` file exists.

2.Open cmd and type nuget spec. File with `.nuspec` extension will be created.

3.Open the created file and add tag:

```
<files> <file src="..\..\SomeRoot\**\*.*" target="libs\net461" /> </files>
```

4.Execute nuget pack A.csproj –IncludeReferencedProjects in cmd. File with `.nupkg` extension gets created.

5.Go to visual studio. In NuGet package manager settings, Add in “Package Sources” and provide path where your `.nupkg` and `.nuspec` file exists.

6.Close Nuget package manager and again open it. Now you can find it in your created package source under browse tab.

Note: Your `.nuspec` file should be like :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <metadata  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <id>ABC.XYZ.FL</id>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    <title>ABC.XYZ.FL</title>
    <authors>ABC</authors>
    <owners>ABC</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Framework that will be used to create objects in XYZ world</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>2016</copyright>
    <tags>ABC.XYZ.FL</tags>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\Debug\*.dll" target="lib\net461" />
  </files>
</package>
```

The following links contains more details about creating nuget package and hosting it locally:

https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package

https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds

https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-file

See if this helps.

Comment: @ShortlyFD its just a example of project root. Refer sample bottom of my answer. `<file src="bin\Debug\*.dll" target="lib\net461" />`